# Rotate image in IKImageBrowserView. Cocoa/Objective C

Tags: objective-c, image, macos, cocoa, ikimagebrowserview

Im looking for your help, with Cocoa IKImageBrowserView.

I have that browser, and images inside that. The images are taken from the folder that I do provide to it. Kinda like that:

```
[importedImages removeAllObjects];
[images removeAllObjects];

NSArray *onlyPNGs = [self getAllPngsInLibraryFolder];

NSString *imagesPath = [[FileHelperManager defaultManager] getPathToImagesFolder];

for(NSString *str in onlyPNGs)
{
    NSString *mergedPath = [imagesPath stringByAppendingString:str];
    [self addAnImageWithPath:mergedPath];
}

[self updateDatasource];
```

When I do chose particular image from ImageBrowser, I show it in NSImageView, and provide an ability to modify some parameters of this image in database where I do store information about all of them. 
The problem what I have met is - I want to support the rotation change of chosen image. I can rotate without any problem an NSImageView preview of selected image, but how can I rotate then this image inside ImageBrowser?
Would be good if somebody can help me with that.

Here is an illustration of what I do try to achieve.

[image: illustration of what I do try to achieve]

So, steps 1,2 are ok, but how can I do step 3?

Comment: Just ideas. Save yourself some work https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/ImageBrowserViewAppearance/Listings/ImageBrowserCell_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009013-ImageBrowserCell_m-DontLinkElementID_6  + https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/IKImageView/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004704-CH3-BCIHFHHB

Comment: Or save rotated image and reloadDataSource

Comment: can I rotate image itself, I mean .jpg or whatever file like I do with nsimageview? if so - how can I do that?

Comment: I gave you ideas not solution, sry.